# Absolute value of definite integral: If $\big|\int^b_af(x) dx \big|\le(b-a)^2$ prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals, absolute-value

> Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. If for any bounded interval $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ we have
>   $$\Bigg|\int^b_af(x) dx  \Bigg|\le(b-a)^2$$
>   Prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I've been looking at this statement for a few hours. It seems very simple but I can't really see a good place to start. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider the function 
\begin{align}
F_a(x) = \int^x_a f(t)\ dt
\end{align}
then we see that $F_a(a) = 0$ and 
\begin{align}
|F_a(x)-F_a(a)| \le (x-a)^2.
\end{align}
Now see what you can say about $f(a)$.

**Remark**: Under the suggestion of @zipirovich, I made some modification to the hint. The solution will be in the comments.

Comment: It seems that in your approach we choose and fix a point $a$ first and then set up this function $F(x)$. Then I don't see why $|F(x)|\le(x-a)^2$ implies that $F$ should be a constant... What if $F(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x-a)^2$?

Comment: @zipirovich You have to vary $a$. Note that $F_a'(a) = f(a)$, which means the derivative of $F_a'$ is independent of $a$.

Comment: If you vary $a$, then you don't have a certain function $F(x)$ -- you have a whole lot of different functions $F_a(x)$.

Comment: @zipirovich Fix $a$. All I want to prove is that $f(a) = 0$. Well, I consider the function $F_a(x)$ defined as above. By the FTC, I see that $F'_a(a) = f(a)$. By the hypothesis, I see that $F'_a(a) = 0$. So $f(a) = 0$.

Comment: Oh, I see it now! Now your last comment does present a solution. But your original post didn't (and still doesn't). The condition $|F_a(x)-F(a)|\le (x-a)^2$ indeed implies that $F'_a(a)=0$ -- the derivative of **this** function is zero at **this** point. But in and by itself this condition does not imply at all that the function is constant.

Comment: Well, it's a hint for a reason. Maybe, a vague hint, but still a hint.

Answer (score 5):

Proceeding by contradiction, suppose WLOG that $f(0) = \delta > 0$. By choosing $\varepsilon > 0$ small enough
$$ \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_{-\varepsilon/2}^{\varepsilon/2} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x $$
can be made arbitrarily close to $\delta$ (hint: mean value theorem for integrals) and greater than $\varepsilon$. This is a contradiction, of course.

Answer (score 4):

For every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we consider interval $[x,x+\epsilon]$ then by mean-value theorem for integrals there exists $x\leq\xi\leq x+\epsilon$
$$\Big|\int_{x}^{x+\epsilon}f(t)dt\Big|=\Big|\epsilon f(\xi)\Big|\leq\epsilon^2$$
now $\epsilon\to0$, then $f(x)=0$

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\dfrac{1}{2\epsilon}\displaystyle\int_{B_{\epsilon}(x)}f(y)dy\rightarrow f(x)$ by Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem (I know this is a little bit over killed, since many people have provided answer here, so I come out with a little bit fancier one), as $\left|\displaystyle\int_{B_{\epsilon}(x)}f(y)dy\right|\leq 4\epsilon^{2}$, then $\dfrac{1}{2\epsilon}\displaystyle\int_{B_{\epsilon}(x)}f(y)dy\rightarrow 0$, so $f(x)=0$.

Comment: In this very special case, Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem can be justified by Mean Value Theorem (the integral version) because $f$ is continuous.